# What is the unit of time developed by Facebook by which common video bit rates are evenly divisible?

Tags: video, bitrate

I saw an article a couple of years ago about a tiny unit of time that was developed and is used internally by Facebook. Nearly all common video bit rates are evenly divisible by this new unit so it simplifies some of the related math. I can't find anything about it now. Does anyone recall seeing any info on this unit? Can anyone provide any references to it?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/OculusVR/Flicks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks szatmary. That's exactly what I was looking for. In short, 1 flick = 1/705600000 second. Details are at [github.com/OculusVR/Flicks](https://github.com/OculusVR/Flicks) as mentioned in the comment above.